# MYSQL to HSQLDB migration issue

Tags: mysql, spring, hsqldb, liquibase

I have an issue with HSQLDB, I have a MySql database that I'm dumping to an in memory HSQLDB i get the following error when I run the script:  `Error: unexpected token: (` which is on a create table script and the offending line is `TINYINT(3)`
if I remove the brackets and the number it works fine, this is a valid declaration on MYSQL and I have tried turning MYSQL compatibility on by changing my url to: `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dataSource;sql.syntax_mys=true` but this still doesn't work. :(

just as additional info I'm using a Spring hibernate connection and using Liquibase to do the dumping from MySQL to HSQLDB and I'm running HSQLDB v2.3.2

Comment: Switch to HSQLDB 2.3.3 for its more extended MySQL compatibility mode. The TINYINT(3) is just a verbose form of TINYINT.

Comment: thanks, will upgrade now and let you know

Comment: hi @fredt upgrading my HSQLDB version doesn't solve this issue, I still get the same error, is there a way to set HSQLDB to igonore the braces after a variable if it doesn't need them?

Comment: You should remove the braces. There are other improvements in the upgrade.

Comment: removing the braces is not the option for me cause this is an automated process on build, but thanks for your help

Comment: This will be supported in the next version. If there are other unsupported elements in the script, you can report them and they will be supported too.

Comment: i have a list actually
1. Grave Accent symbol (`) used by mysql the same way HSQLDB uses double qoutes.
2. NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' -> DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL 
3.  LOCK TABLES "TABLE_NAME" WRITE; its singulat TABLE in HSQL but MYSQL is plural
4. UNLOCK TABLES; doesn't work on HSQLDB
5. index creation on create statement: KEY "FK_POSITION_TYPE_CONF" ("ID") doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. #1, #2, #5 are already supported in version 2.3.3.

Comment: Ok, thanks @fredt will check these out as they were noted before i did the upgrade

Answer (score 2):

SQL Syntax especially DDL is not very well portable between different databases. You will have to learn the correct syntax for create table in HSQLDB witch is somewhat different from MySQL.

You can not just export table definition from one flavor of database and import into another. 
Would be great if this would be the case but SQL Standard is quite loose...

Comment: but HSQLD supposedly has a compatibility mode for MYSQL and I turned this on, that's why I expected this to work

Comment: As was pointed out by @fredt the problem is that your flavor of HSQLDB most likely does not allow for a size specification when using TINYINT. So removing all braces after TINYINT would help. When you work with something like Liquidbase you should consider using a more neutral format like YML for your dumps. This could migrate the incompatibility between different SQL versions.

Comment: thanks @tobias-kremer 

I'm gonna upgrade and see if that works, I also don't wanna remove the braces manually cause this whole process will be useless for me if it needs some manual intervention

Comment: the problem is not the data, but the actual table structure as the data is in csv format already

Comment: Yes the problem is in the table structure. I thougth this to be obvious as your error clearly says it is a ```CREATE TABLE``` that is not working. Have you considered switching to a different tool like http://flywaydb.org/? If you have your data as CSV you could also try using Hibernate Auto DDL to create your tables and than just load the data to the tables.

Comment: Hey @tobias-kremer I tried using hibernate but then it becomes an issue to insert data as hibernates also creates constraints and the data is not inserted in the same order that the constraints go

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a DDL-Script, you can add `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX MYS TRUE;` to the top of it, see also [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_sql_conformance) (Table 13.29. MySQL Style Syntax).

You may use this only for tests though; if you want to fully migrate to HSQLDB, changing the scripts themselves is sure the long term solution.

Comment: sql.syntax_mys=true does the same thing